# Automatically accept placeholders in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I have just moved over from TexMaker to TexStudio and I have to say I really like it so far, however I find the box around placeholders super distracting. I know I can just hit Cmd+Shift+K to get rid of them but I find that also annoying and I know I can just turn off the Auto-Complete feature entirely. I like the autocomplete, particularly for the parenthesis, so is there any way I can just accept all the placeholders automatically while I am typing?

Comment: that is one of the features I like the most in TeXstudio. Combined with CTRL + D it is powerfull enough to edit multiple `\begin{}...\end{}` at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Just continue typing. e.g. if you have completed `\textbf{[text]}` (square brackets denoting the placehoder frame) and written into the placeholder: `\textbf{[hello world]}`. The cursor is in front of the closing curly brace. Retype that brace. Then the cursor will move past it and the placeholder vanishes.